# Sending hex values via extraPuTTY adding erroneous data

Tags: lua, char, hex, putty

I'm trying make ExtraPuTTY do the equivalent of:

https://github.com/SolidRun/u-boot-armada38x/blob/u-boot-2013.01-15t1-clearfog/download-serial.sh

I figured I could use a lua script to interrupt the boot sequence then send the u-boot file via xmodem.

Problem is when I try to send using ExtraPuTTY the first hex value changes from BB to C2 BB

```
lua_senddata(string.format("%c%c%c%c%c%c%c%c",0xbb,0x11,0x22,0x33,0x44,0x55,0x66,0x77), false);
```

Output:

```
Rec: C2 BB 
Rec: 11 
Rec: 22 
Rec: 33 
Rec: 44 
Rec: 55 
Rec: 66 
Rec: 77
```

I also wrote a binary file and tried to read it in then send but ran into the same problem.

```
function readAll(file)
    local f = io.open(file, "rb")
    local content = f:read("*all")
    f:close()
    return content
end

local data = readAll([[C:\test\WakeUpData_Send.bin]])
lua_senddata(data, false)
```

My best guess is the conversion to Char what's adding the extra C2 to the start of the data block.

Using: http://www.serialporttool.com/CommEcho.htm to test with.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Well turns out it was the text encoding been set to UTF-8 was translating the character code using the UTF-8 code table to C2 BB.

In putty I changed the Window > Translation > Remote character set to 'Use font encoding' and it wrote the hex codes directly as passed to it.