# How to generate a serial port BREAK condition in lua

Tags: lua, putty

I am using ExtraPuTTY's Lua scripting capability to control a device over a serial port.  There are multiple embedded modules in this device and a command which allows the console port to become a "tunnel" to an embedded module.  To escape back to the device's command line interface a break must be sent.  When typing commands at the keyboard I can select "Special Command" "Break" to send the break.  How can I send a "break" from within a lua script?

I'm using *lua_senddata()* to send commands to the device.  Is there another function to send a break?  Is there an escape sequence that indicates break, kind of like \n indicates new line?

I am not sure if this is a general Lua question or an ExtraPuTTY specific issue.

Answer (score 0):

That's a key-combo of CTRL-BREAK - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Break_key

xev shows those keycodes as:

```
KeyPress event,
    state 0x10, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R)

KeyPress event,
    state 0x14, keycode 127 (keysym 0xff6b, Break)


KeyRelease event,
    state 0x14, keycode 127 (keysym 0xff6b, Break)

KeyRelease event,
    state 0x14, keycode 105 (keysym 0xffe4, Control_R)
```

I believe you just need to send `0xffe4 0xff6b` - according to this answer, you'd do so, like this:

[Sending hex values via extraPuTTY adding erroneous data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39865208/sending-hex-values-via-extraputty-adding-erroneous-data)

```
lua_senddata( string.format( '%c%c%c%c', 0xff, 0xe4, 0xff, 0x6b ), false )
```

> change **Window > Translation > Remote character set** to 'Use font encoding' and write hex codes directly